# Не работает передача файлов на сервер <input type=file>

Tags: php, html, файлы

Доброго времени суток! Мне нужно сделать передачу в PHP - файл множественное число файлов. Для этого я сделал форму с enctype="multipart/form-data" и input с типом file и атрибут multiple. Однако, на сервер не приходят файлы и в массиве $_FILES пусто.
При клике на #uploadButton происходит клик по #fileUpload

```
<form class="form_style1 order_form" action="handlers/sendmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="order-form" method="POST">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Оформить заказ</legend>
  <div class="input_container">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ф.И.О *" />
    <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Телефон *" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" />
    <input type="text" name="vuz" placeholder="ВУЗ *" />
    <select required="required" name="cat">
      <option value="0">Категория работы *</option>
      <option disabled="disabled">--Магистерская диссертация--</option>
      <option value="Конструкторско - технологическое обеспечение машиностроительных производств (технология машиностроения)">
        Конструкторско - технологическое обеспечение машиностроительных производств (технология машиностроения)
      </option>
      <option disabled="disabled">--Дипломный проект--</option>
      <option value="Наземные транспортно - технологические средства">Наземные транспортно - технологические средства</option>
      <option disabled="disabled">--Выпускная работа--</option>
      <option value="Конструкторско - технологическое обеспечение машиностроительных производств">Конструкторско - технологическое обеспечение машиностроительных производств</option>
      <option value="Машиностроение (обработка металлов давлением)">Машиностроение (обработка металлов давлением)</option>
      <option disabled="disabled">--Курсовая работа--</option>
      <option value="Технология машиностроения (ТМ)">Технология машиностроения (ТМ)</option>
      <option value="Режущие инструменты (РИ)">Режущие инструменты (РИ)</option>
      <option value="Детали машин">Детали машин</option>
      <option value="Теория механизмов и машин">Теория механизмов и машин</option>
      <option value="борудование машиностроительного производства, нормирование точности.">Оборудование машиностроительного производства, нормирование точности.</option>
      <option disabled="disabled">--Контрольная работа--</option>
      <option value="Физика">Физика</option>
      <option value="Математика">Математика</option>
    </select>
    <textarea placeholder="Комментарии и пожелания" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple id="fileUpload"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="order">
    <div class="uploadButtonWrap">
      <div class="uploadButton" id="uploadButton">Прикрепить файлы</div>
      <div id="uploadedFiles"></div>
      <div class="uploadButton deleteUploadedFile" id="deleteUploadedFiles">Удалить все файлы</div>
    </div>
    <button class="submit_button1" type="submit">Оформить заказ</button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

Укажите в имени поля явно, что это массив. Т.е. надо назвать не `<input type="file" name="files" ...>`
а `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ... >`